# Update fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i make a repertoire. I have the list of the contact and a button to add a new contact. When I click on the button add, a new fragment open and I can write the informations of the contact. When I click on add, I go back to the first fragment and I want to refresh the list of the contacts.

My contacts are save in a class which is a Singleton, so to get my list of contact, i need to write `Contacts.getInstance().getContacts();` (don't cry about how the conception is, it's not really my code, I simplified it to make this topic easier to understand).

All work but not the refresh of the list of contacts.
So there is my code :

there is the code of the event of the button which add the new contact

```
buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String name = ((EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.nom)).getText().toString();
                    Contacts.getInstance().add(name);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                }
            }
        }); :
```

When this event reach, then the Fragment which show all contacts is showed and I used this to make the update :

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LinearLayout listContact = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.listContact);
        listContact.removeAllViews();
        getListContact(listContact);
    }
```

This method work but it's not refreshing when this fragment is show after the adding of the new contact. It's work when I lock/unlock my phone for an example.

I know why, it's because the event `onResume()` is attached to an Activity and not to a Fragment. I have search on the net and I don't understand the solutions which are proposed.So, what change should I do?

EDIT :

I call the AddContactFragment from your ListContactFragment by using this :

```
addContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                FragmentAddContact fragment2 = new FragmentAddContact();
                transaction.add(R.id.myFrameLayout, fragment2);
                transaction.addToBackStack("FragmentAddContact");
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try the above code in `onViewStateRestored(Bundle)` method of the Fragment.

Comment: This doing nothing : @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout listContact = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.listContact);
        listContact.removeAllViews();
        getListContact(listContact);
    }

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting the updated contact list in your `getListContact` method?

Comment: Yep 100% sure, i have said on the topic that the list is updated when i lock/unlock my phone for an example. The problem is about how to refresh a fragment because the onResume event isn't call when we do a popbackstack of the fragment ^^

Comment: How do you call the `AddContactFragment` from your `ListContactFragment`? By using `replace()` or `hide()` method in the FragmentManager?

Comment: 1. You can reference to your `Fragment` as long as it's live and attached to the `HolderView` follow this link to refresh the Fragment http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html 2. I use the above for a long time until I saw `RxJava` and I switch to `RxJava` if you want to use `RxJava` respond to walk you through.

Comment: put the code of getListContact(listContact) method

Comment: @PrerakSola i have edited my post, check on the bottom you will see how and i do develop in android just for this school project and i have no time to learn a new framework ^^ i will check the doc another time ^^